# Mounting a network filesystem into schroot

Tags: mount, afs, chroot

I'm using a network file system (AFS) and I would like to also mount it into my schroot. Adding a line to /etc/schroot/mount-defaults, with `bind` or `rbind` in the options didn't help: schroot always mounts the directory with `bind`, and it remains empty in the chroot.

My current solution is a script that remounts the /afs directory with `rbind` after the schroot has been set up.

Is there a way to make schroot use rbind directly?

Comment: have you ever found/received an answer (maybe elsewhere) to your question? If so, would you kindly share it with us? I, too, want to mount an NFS resource into a schroot environment.

Comment: I never got an answer with schroot. My solution at the time was like I wrote in the question, to mount that specific resource after schroot has started.

Answer (score 0):

```
# means run with root or sudo

1. Create a mountpoint
# mkdir /mount/point

2. Mount /proc /sys /dev to chroot
# mount -o bind /proc /mount/point/proc
# mount -o bind /dev /mount/point/dev
# mount -o bind /dev/pts /mount/point/dev/pts
# mount -o bind /sys /mount/point/sys

3. Copy resolv.conf to networking
# cp /etc/resolv.conf /mount/point/etc/resolv.conf

4.Open bash in chroot
# chroot /mount/point /bin/bash

5. Do what you have to do and then exit chroot
exit
```

Also see: http://fermilinux.fnal.gov/documentation/tips/mount-bind-chroot

Comment: That's basically what he wants to do, but the point is that schroot automates these steps, and he's trying to also get mounting of the network filesystem automated.

Comment: Your link is dead :(